# Filter By Date in a GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I need some help for a Filter By Date with LINQ query.

So,

This is my Class:

```
public class MyList
    {
        public string Ent { get; set; }
        public string Con { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }
        public double? Med { get; set; }
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    }
```

My Query:

```
public IEnumerable<MyList> LoadData()
    {
        var ctx = new DbContext();

        var query = (from t in ctx.tblTimes.AsQueryable().Where(s => s.Included == true)
                     join av in ctx.tblPrincipal on t.AID equals av.AID
                     join c in ctx.tblCon on av.ConID equals c.ConID
                     join e in ctx.tblEnt on av.EntID equals e.EntID
                     group t by new
                     {
                         c.Name,
                         e.Entity
                     } into grp
                     select new MyList
                     {
                         Con = grp.Key.Name,
                         Ent = grp.Key.Entity,
                         Count = grp.Count(),
                         Med = grp.Average(s => s.Time),
                         Data = grp.Select(s => s.tblPrincipal.Data).FirstOrDefault()
                     });
        if (CmbCon.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var selected = (tblCon)CmbCon.SelectedItem;
            query = query.Where(s => s.Name == selected.Name);
        }
        if (CmbEnt.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var selected = (tblEnt)CmbEnt.SelectedItem;
            query = query.Where(s => s.Entity == selected.Entity);
        }
        if(DataFrom.Checked && DataTo.Checked)
        {
            DateTime inicio = DataAgendFrom.Value;
            DateTime fim = DataAgendTo.Value;
            query = query.Where(s => s.Data >= inicio && s.Data <= fim);
        }
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

My OnLoad event:

```
private void Form_OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        data.DataSource = LoadData();
        data.Columns["Data"].Visible = false;
    }
```

So, if I filter by the 2 ComboBox, the filter works fine and results are showed correctly, but if I filter by Dates, if gives my all, like there's no Filters...

Some images from Inicio and Fim Date...

**Inicio**

[image]

**Fim**

[image]

In my MSSQL Database, I have 2 records with Date like image below... The date range above perfectly fits 1 of my Database record.

[image]

But, When I apply dates in Image (Inicio and Fim), I get the 2 records (Count = 2 and Average = Average of 2 records).
Any ideas?

**EDIT**: After some testings, I found that with range dates above, the query returns all records from database when only should return 1 record that fits range, but with another range (Inicio 2018-06-19 00:00:00; Fim 2018-06-19 23:59:59), no results are returned at all, which is wrong because the second record in database fits in this range! Can't understand, but I suspect the problem is this piece of code:

```
Data = grp.Select(s => s.tblPrincipal.Data).FirstOrDefault()
```

This is returning all records if the first record fits date range, if first records does not fit range, no results are returned!

Thanks

Comment: what you mean with "if I filter by Dates, if gives my all, like there's no Filters"? what is "Dates"?

Comment: Who is `DataFrom` and `DataTo`? `DataFrom.Value` returns a string or a DateTime? if it's a string, you probably should parse to DateTime

Comment: Yes, Like there's no filter applied! With Dates I mean Date Range DataFrom and DataTo. These 2 are 2 DatePickers I have in Form to filter date from DataFrom To DataTo Range.

Comment: DataFrom and DataTo are 2 DateTimePickers in Form, which is supposed to filter a Range of Dates to apply in Data Property (s => s.Data >= DataFrom... I've changed my query DataFrom.Checked and DataTo.Checked converting to Date...

Comment: Can you show the value from DataFrom and DataTo?

Comment: I don't know if this is your problem, but you're filtering in the `OnLoad`event from the form, this means that it will pick the values from when the form was loaded, even if you change later it will not change. If you want to change later, you should either put a button on your form to update the values or pick events from the DatePickers and comboboxes

Comment: @Afonso, I've included some pictures where you can see DataFrom and DataTo values...

Comment: @Magnetron, like I said, both Comboboxes filtering works. Only my Date filters not working.

Comment: Your "Count" and "Average" aggregates are calculated without any filter though? - That filter is applied to the selected "MyList" objects only after they have been calculated?

Comment: Throw a `query.ToList()` in there, or inspect `query` and enumerate it, before you apply any of the filters (ie after the group by but before the further queries). What is in there? How many records? What are the `data` values? are they as expected?

Comment: @Sam, Yes, If no filter is applied, Count will show 2 and Average will show 258,5. If I filter Con or Ent Comboboxes, it shows Count = 1 and Average = 458 for example. And it's correct like this. But, when I filter the Date, then is like no filter is done at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to apply your filter earlier to impact the aggregate values, like this :

```
public IEnumerable<MyList> LoadData()
{
    var ctx = new DbContext();

    var set = ctx.tblTimes.AsQueryable();


   if(DataFrom.Checked && DataTo.Checked)
   {
       DateTime inicio = DataAgendFrom.Value;
       DateTime fim = DataAgendTo.Value;
       set = set.Where(s => s.Data >= inicio && s.Data <= fim);
    }

    var query = (from t in set.Where(s => s.Included == true)
                 join av in ctx.tblPrincipal on t.AID equals av.AID
                 join c in ctx.tblCon on av.ConID equals c.ConID
                 join e in ctx.tblEnt on av.EntID equals e.EntID
                 group t by new
                 {
                     c.Name,
                     e.Entity
                 } into grp
                 select new MyList
                 {
                     Con = grp.Key.Name,
                     Ent = grp.Key.Entity,
                     Count = grp.Count(),
                     Med = grp.Average(s => s.Time),
                     Data = grp.Select(s => s.tblPrincipal.Data).FirstOrDefault()
                 });
    if (CmbCon.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        var selected = (tblCon)CmbCon.SelectedItem;
        query = query.Where(s => s.Name == selected.Name);
    }
    if (CmbEnt.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        var selected = (tblEnt)CmbEnt.SelectedItem;
        query = query.Where(s => s.Entity == selected.Entity);
    }

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But still no Date filter with your suggestion.

Comment: @CarlosFerreira Are you sure? The error in your query is that you only filter on the first date in `grp`, which means that `grp` may contain dates outside the specified interval. The query in this answer shouldn't return any of these because the data is filtered before grouping. Anyway, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I am probably saying something stupid after long work day, but what I see that both your database elements perfectly fits to range of the `inicio` and `fim`.

DataTo and DateFrom and your dataset have the same day, month and year. Your dataset have hours that between 00 (data from) and 23 (data to).

Also, I may assume that you have different formats inside your Database and code. 
For example:

```
Database: mm/dd/yyyy, 24hours
Code: dd/mm/yyyy, 12hours
```

That's might also occure the problem.
Hope it helps. If something not clear enough, please, do not hesitate to contact me.

Comment: Days are different- 9 and 19

Comment: @Dmitry Pavliv, totally hard day, sorry. What about format? And does member query returns two elements? Or you getting two elements later on?

Comment: The Date format are similar on Database and Code... Format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

Comment: I'm almost sure the problem is in here! `Data = grp.Select(s => s.tblPrincipal.Data).FirstOrDefault()`. What I'm trying to achieve here is get Date Property from Database so I can compare in the query!